# Telegram: How to find Group Chat ID?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I've been trying to solve this for three days and none pf the solutions I've found online seem to work, so I am going to have to ask for help.

I want to create a Telegram "Group Chat" to be used by members of a club I'm in. I created the chat named with the initials of the club, like: "ABCD" and added some members. Now I want to automate the sending of occasional messages to the group for all members to see. Weather forecast, random photograph from our gallery, etc.

Using @BotFather I created a bot called "ABCDbot" and noted the token for that bot. Now I have two "ABCD"s on my browser left side-panel. Selecting one gives me "ABCD bot" and selecting the other gives me "ABCD 123 members".

Using a perl script and LWP I can send a photo using

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use feature 'say';
use LWP;
my $api = LWP::UserAgent->new ();

my $chat_id = '1234567890';
my $photo = '/home/user/gallery/photo999.jpg';

my $response = $api->post(
  "https://api.telegram.org/bot<ABCDbot's token>/sendPhoto",
  [ 'chat_id' => $chat_id,
    'caption' => 'Photo Randomly Selected by the gallery',
    'photo' => $photo,
  ],
  'Content_Type' => 'form-data',
);
if ($response->is_success) {
  say "Response..... Success!";
} else {
  say "Response..... Failure!";
}
```

This works, providing I give it a legitimate chat_id and a legitimate file to send.
But the trouble is: **I can't find the chat_id** for the group chat with 123 members! Every method I've tried now proves to be obsolete or simply doesn't return the desired chat_id for the ABCD group chat. I can get my own chat ID or that of individual members of the group, or of the bot itself, and can successfully send photos, messages, etc to those destinations, but I just can't send anything to the group.

Can anybody walk me through the process of getting the chat_id for my group chat? Or direct me to a document describing an up-to-date, working method for obtaining same?

Assistance much appreciated.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## Method 1 ([Web A](https://web.telegram.org/a))

> This is based on JayeshRocks’s question with some extra steps to make the ID work with Bot API.

1. Login to [Telegram Web A](https://web.telegram.org/a).
2. Open the chat you want to get its ID.
3. Your browser’s address should look like https://web.telegram.org/a/#-1527776602.
4. Remove the scheme, the hostname and the path, keeping the anchor so your result looks like #-1527776602.
5. Replace “#-” with “-100” so it looks like -1001527776602.
6. You can now use your final result which should look like -1001527776602.

## Method 2 (Private Supergroups)

If the chat is a private channel/supergroup, you can do the following:

1. Copy a link of a message. (It will look like https://t.me/c/1527776602/1002.)
2. Remove the protocol and domain name, so it looks like c/1527776602/1002.
3. Remove the first and last path, so it looks like 1527776602.
4. Append “-100” to the beginning of the result, so it looks like -1001527776602.
5. You can now use your final result which looks like -1001527776602.

## Method 3 (Third-Party Bots)

If you trust 3rd party bots, there are many of them. A known one is [@MissRose_bot](https://t.me/MissRose_bot) which you can add it to your group and use its /id command. Another one is [@usinfobot](https://t.me/usinfobot) which works inline and only for public chats.

Comment: I tried method #1 (WebZ) and was successful when sending to the group chat using the chat_id derived from the URL.

I will experiment more with different message types, but in the mean time I send you my thanks.

Comment: When you think this answer resolves your problem, you can click the checkmark on the left to mark your question as resolved.

Answer (score 1):

To get a telegram group ID you need to open the group on https://web.telegram.org/z/ when you do so click on the group you want to gain the ID of then if you look at the URL it will say something like https://web.telegram.org/z/#-1234567 and the numbers there is the ID of the telegram group!
Hope this helps

Comment: Ok, I tried Opening the group on  https://web.telegram.org/z/ and got a number like "-1234567890'. Using this number as a chat_id, I send a photo using the code given above. The response I get is:

{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: chat not found"}

I *am* including the leading dash/minus sign. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Python code for a simple Telegram bot that prints any chat ID. Add your bot to the group chat and send a message **mentioning the bot by @** in the group chat.

To create a bot and get the API token, write to `@BotFather`.

```
import telebot
bot = telebot.TeleBot('token')


@bot.message_handler(func=lambda _: True)
def handle(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'{message.chat.id}')


def main():
    bot.infinity_polling()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```